# Strange Text Formatting When Forwarding/Replying To An E-Mail In Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, text-formatting

A client has come to me with a strange issue. When she replies to an e-mail the text she writes will be formatted in the standard Outlook 2010 colour of blue. However, she doesn't want this to happen, so she highlights all of the text and changes the colour to black.

But, when the recipient receives the e-mail some words are still blue. She could have a 20 word sentence, two of the words in the middle (well in any order, it does seem very random) will be the standard blue. It could also be a longish e-mail, and only two words be blue, or a short e-mail and loads of words would turn out blue.

Has anyone came across this sort of issue before?

Cheers!

Comment: I'm inclined to say its a user error unless you know for sure otherwise.

Comment: I've watched her reply and I can't see her doing anything wrong to be honest. She highlights the whole section of text that she's written, formats it black, and it looks black on her computer. When the e-mail is viewed on other computers its where the problems start. Also, I thought they may be hyperlinks but they aren't.

Comment: I have had similar things, but with printing. It sounds like corruption. I would repair the install, and have her start a new e-mail thread (it could be the e-mail itself if only one), and see if it still happens.

Comment: I will try that today and let you know how I get on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the Windows Style applied to her computer was causing Outlook to behave like that. I changed her theme to default and it solved the problem.